# I can't place widgets in Qt Creator Design Mode

Tags: qt-creator, qt-designer

I need help solving a problem with Qt Creator. Qt Creator 10.0.1 is  installed from the online Qt installer. I am using Ubuntu 23.04. When I creating a project and trying to change the mainwindow.ui file in Design Mode, I cannot place widgets.

For clarity, I recorded a video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qlzAaCi6uf5V8Z7dbBqdB2WHfTCVxtuK/view

I reinstalled Qt Creator, along with Qt Designer, and it still didn't give any results. If I use Qt Designer as a separate application, everything works as it should. Tell me what's wrong, thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I faced exactly the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't decided yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a known [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2715). Switching to Wayland solve the problem for me. See also [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2013235) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/QtFramework/comments/12t5rr6/cant_drag_and_drop_widgets_in_qt_designer_im_on/).
Separate Qt Designer behaves exactly the same way in my case (didn't work on X11, works on Wayland).

Comment: In my case, changing X11 to Wayland and back did not have any effect (I was originally on Wayland), but the second link helped me solve this issue. In particular, I think it has to do with the `mutter` package. Probably, it should be updated, after that everything should work